# Facing Issue with Xmlwriter while writing nested items

Tags: xmlwriter

I’m trying to use Xmlwriter to generate HTML output and came across this issue where HTML is not generating as expected.

My code look something like this.

```
writer.WriteStartElement("div");
writer.WriteAttributeString("class", "test");
writer.Flush();

 //Load other control which write to same stream.
 //other control generate o/p like this <div id=”other control”></div>

writer.WriteFullEndElement();
writer.Flush();
```

Output of this code is generating like this.

```
<div class="test" 
   <div id=”other control”></div>
></div>
```

But the expected output is

```
<div class="test">
   <div id=”other control”></div>
</div>
```

Anyone faced same type of issue ? 
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

New to programing, so not sure about this

```
//writer.Flush(); //if you need a flush to come before your control

writer.WriteStartElement("div");

writer.WriteStartAttribute("class");

writer.WriteValue("test"); // OR writer.WriteString("test");

writer.WriteEndAttribute(); //perhaps this way is handled differently. 

writer.WriteStartElement("control");// with no attributes to confuse it you might want to name it div

//then your other control stuff

writer.WriteEndElement();// end of the control element 

writer.WriteEndElement();// end of the div.

writer.Flush();
```

I think the `WriteEndElement` decides whether it will be a /> or >< /elementname> or >UnknownStuff< / elementname>, so if it has something like your control or maybe the flush, that it does not know how to handle your control.
Since the last thing it was writing was an attribute, it regards your control as a odd looking attribute. 
By placing your control in a element that could be called control or < div > the WriteEndElement might think it's a odd looking element.

Imagine how you might make the `WriteEndElement` if you were writing the `XMLwriter` class.
What is it going to deal with in it's life cycle. 
How does it recognize that their are to be no more attributes because maybe you can trick it somehow.

If you find a way to get it working please put your answer up because I know I have been helped by reading years old forums and I have been noticing that usually the question is answer about six mouths latter which if your working on anything you probably thought of what to do by that time.